# Set height of textarea based on text content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using this example to set the height of the textarea.

but the size of the textarea is not set automatically if the textarea has a value.

https://codesandbox.io/s/autosize-textarea-forked-wdowvr?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const val = evt.target?.value;

    setValue(val);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label htmlFor="review-text">Review:</label>
      <textarea
        id="review-text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onInput={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
          e.currentTarget.style.height = e.currentTarget.scrollHeight + "px";
        }}
        ref={textAreaRef}
        rows={1}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6KEY.png)

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippets to adjust the height on loading the component.

Just for demo purposes:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(
  "already has a value with\nmore text\nand even more"
);
const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
```

You can access the ref once it is set. `useEffect` will do the trick here.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (textAreaRef && textAreaRef.current) {
    textAreaRef.current.style.height = textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
}, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/autosize-textarea-forked-symr7p?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set the height once the `DOM` is mounted. This way it can respond to whatever value is in there before any user input.
I did this with the `useEffect` hook. (Don't forget to `import` it from `react`).

I also tweaked the method of changing the height a bit, because it wasn't working properly.

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const textAreaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    const val = evt.target?.value;

    setValue(val);
  };

  const resizeTextarea = (t: HTMLTextAreaElement) => {
    t.style.height = "auto";
    const p = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(t, null).getPropertyValue("padding-top")) 
            + parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(t, null).getPropertyValue("padding-bottom"));
    t.style.height = t.scrollHeight - p + "px";
  }

  const handleInput = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    resizeTextarea(e.currentTarget);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const t = textAreaRef.current;
    if (t != null) {
      t.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
      resizeTextarea(t);
    }
 },[]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label htmlFor="review-text">Review:</label>
      <textarea
        id="review-text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        onInput={handleInput}
        ref={textAreaRef}
        rows={1}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/autosize-textarea-forked-s39ur2?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1172